# Why does "page allocation failure" occur whereas there are still enough memory(i.e. "58*4096kB (C)") that could be used?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, memory

Why does "page allocation failure" occur whereas there are still "58*4096kB (C)" that could be used?

You see, the kernel complains when allocating memory with the size of order:10(i.e.page allocation failure: order:10). But there are free blocks indeed(i.e. "58*4096kB (C)" ). So I think it should not complain since there are enough free memory indeed.

Here is the related log:

```
[ 2161.623563] xxxx: page allocation failure: order:10, mode:0x2084020(GFP_ATOMIC|__GFP_COMP)
[ 2161.632085] CPU: 0 PID: 179 Comm: AiApp Not tainted 4.9.56 #53
[ 2161.637947] 
Call Trace:
[<802f63f2>] dump_stack+0x1e/0x3c
[<800f6cf4>] warn_alloc+0x100/0x148
[<800f709c>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x2bc/0xb5c
[<801120fe>] kmalloc_order+0x26/0x48
[<80112158>] kmalloc_order_trace+0x38/0x98
[<8012c5d8>] __kmalloc+0xf4/0x12c
[<8048ac78>] alloc_ep_req+0x5c/0x98
[<8048f232>] source_sink_recv+0x2a/0xe0
[<8048f35e>] usb_sourcesink_bulk_read+0x76/0x1c8
[<8048f770>] usb_sourcesink_read+0xfc/0x2c8
[<80134d58>] __vfs_read+0x30/0x108
[<80135c14>] vfs_read+0x94/0x128
[<80136d12>] SyS_read+0x52/0xd4
[<8004a246>] csky_systemcall+0x96/0xe0
[ 2161.689204] Mem-Info:
[ 2161.691518] active_anon:3268 inactive_anon:2 isolated_anon:0
[ 2161.691518]  active_file:1271 inactive_file:89286 isolated_file:0
[ 2161.691518]  unevictable:0 dirty:343 writeback:0 unstable:0
[ 2161.691518]  slab_reclaimable:2019 slab_unreclaimable:644
[ 2161.691518]  mapped:4282 shmem:4 pagetables:59 bounce:0
[ 2161.691518]  free:62086 free_pcp:199 free_cma:60234

[ 2161.724334] Node 0 active_anon:13072kB inactive_anon:8kB active_file:5084kB inactive_file:357144kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:17128kB dirty:1372kB writeback:0kB shmem:16kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no

[ 2161.748626] Normal free:248344kB min:2444kB low:3052kB high:3660kB active_anon:13072kB inactive_anon:8kB active_file:5084kB inactive_file:357144kB unevictable:0kB writepending:1372kB present:1048572kB managed:734568kB mlocked:0kB slab_reclaimable:8076kB slab_unreclaimable:2576kB kernel_stack:608kB pagetables:236kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:796kB local_pcp:796kB free_cma:240936kB
[ 2161.781670] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0

[ 2161.785225] Normal: 4*4kB (UEC) 3*8kB (EC) 3*16kB (UEC) 2*32kB (UE) 2*64kB (UE) 2*128kB (UE) 2*256kB (EC) 1*512kB (E) 3*1024kB (UEC) 3*2048kB (UEC) 58*4096kB (C) = 248344kB
90573 total pagecache pages

[ 2161.803526] 262143 pages RAM
[ 2161.806410] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[ 2161.810264] 78501 pages reserved
[ 2161.813509] 90112 pages cma reserved
```

Comment: I hope to know the direct reasons for the question. You see, there is still enough memory(i.e. “58*4096kB (C)”) that could be used. Why does not pick a block from this order?

Comment: I see, what kernel/linux do you use?  As I said at the beginning, for greater detail I need the system information.

Comment: That is the key information about the 4.9 kernel!  There has been a bug that swap has not been used at certain 4.9 kernel versions.  Read my edit!

Comment: Thank you for your attention to this matter. How did you find this information? Google for keywords?

Comment: You are welcome. I remember this issue as I had this issue when I was testing CentOS 7 on my server. I found it fishy that the free memory was exactly the same as the sice of the swap.   I started to dig around SWAP/memory faults.

Comment: Can I draw the conclusion that the system still has 62086KB free memory since there is "Mem-Info: ...free:62086"?

Comment: `free:62086` tells you you have *62086* free pages.  It is **not** kB.  That is the **248344kB** of free memory which you get some lines below (I have written the count in my answer).

Comment: Thank you. The error repeated again yesterday. I saw "meminfo: ... free:11915 " from `dmesg` when the userspace returned error  whereas it indicates there are still 111MB free memory from 'free -m' at the same time(i.e. free -m outputs free    shared  buff/cache   available  111          18         145          77). Where goes wrong?

Comment: Thank you on accepting the answer.  Did you try to **upgrade** your **kernel**?  The second error *11915 pages* would be *47660kB* (the difference between 111MB vs 47MB could be the `min_free_kbytes`).  What is the size of your swap?  With the `free -m` output it is unclear what you are actually showing.  `free` has 6 columns in total I would need to see the complete output of `free`.

Comment: I can't upgrade the kernel indeed since some patches only could be applied to the current version. I think maybe I find the reasons. I did a lot tests(i.e. `free -k; echo m > /proc/sysrq-trigger ; echo -e "\nMem_info"; dmesg -c | grep free | head -n 1`) . I found you are right the free pages are equivalent to the free memory indicated by `free -m`. Why does the condition aforementioned in my last comment occur? I think it's because there is a time interval between the info of mem_info outputted by the kernel and the executing of `free -m`.

Comment: You need to read the bug reports, those linked in my answer, carefully. (there you could find why this condition occurs - since I'm not sitting at the system it is hard for me based on the data you have provided). If you can't upgrade a kernel, then do a diff between the source of your kernel and the `4.10.8`, which was reported to be fixed.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your generous help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not provide much information,
like what are the condition(s) under which this occurs,
which system (Linux, Android,...) are you running, etc.

Anyways you can start fine-tuning your kernel. 
You could play around with `vm.min_free_kbytes`,
which tells the kernel to keep such memory free (the unit is KiB)
under all circumstances.

From [kernel.org documentation ("Documentation for /proc/sys/vm/*")](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt):

> min_free_kbytes:
>
> This is used to force the Linux VM to keep a minimum number of
> kilobytes<sup>*</sup> free.  The VM uses this number to compute a
> watermark [`WMARK_MIN`] value for each lowmem zone in the system. 
> Each lowmem zone gets a number of reserved free pages based proportionally
> on its size.
>
> Some minimal amount of memory is needed to satisfy `PF_MEMALLOC`
> allocations; if you set this to lower than 1024 KB<sup>**</sup>,
> your system will become subtly broken, and prone to deadlock under high loads.
>
> Setting this too high will OOM your machine instantly.

To change this setting permanently you can do (lowering to 16 MiB):

```
echo "vm.min_free_kbytes=16384" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

To play around and test that everything works,
you can change it just for the current session:

```
sysctl -w vm.min_free_kbytes=16384
```

The source of the information was [kernel.org documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt).

---

Your question is why you have page fault when you have free memory
– even when you have more free memory than specified above?

If you have free memory above the limit specified by `vm.min_free_kbytes`,
then the answer is most likely **memory fragmentation**
(you could have others, like faulty memory modules).

Here are the details:

The order:10 bit tells you indirectly how many pages were requested. 
Such order is considered high-order as it actually requests 2<sup>10</sup> (2^10),
which is 1024 pages or 4096 KiB of continuous memory!

The `mode` are the flags passed to the kernel memory allocator. 
You have a `mode:0x2084020 (GFP_ATOMIC|__GFP_COMP)`
– kernel mode allocator (flags). 
For this one you need to have some kernel source knowledge. 
To explain your flags in detail.

The `GFP_ATOMIC` flag:

> The `GFP_ATOMIC` flag instructs the memory allocator never to block. 
> Use this flag in situations where it cannot sleep — where it must remain
> atomic — such as interrupt handlers, bottom halves and process context
> code that is holding a lock. 
> Because the kernel cannot block the allocation
> and try to free up sufficient memory to satisfy the request,
> an allocation specifying `GFP_ATOMIC` has a lesser chance of
> succeeding than one that does not.  Nonetheless, if your current
> context is incapable of sleeping, it is your only choice. …

The `__GFP_COMP` flag:

> compound page metadata

From include/linux/gfp.h (see [source 1](https://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.4.4/include/linux/gfp.h#L70), [source 2](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/gfp.h)).

> The page frame belongs to extended page

Which comes to the back to the size of memory required. 
Extended page allows you to have 4 MiB page frames instead of just 4 KiB. 
Recommended reading: the [*Linux Kernel*](https://books.google.cz/books?id=h0lltXyJ8aIC&pg=PT320&lpg=PT320&dq=linux%20kernel%20book%20__GFP_COMP&source=bl&ots=gP8nLXcdOS&sig=ACfU3U37YvSNAq1R8wnWrM9z-FbXzHrsjQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi--ea5mpDqAhWI66QKHSCqCfoQ6AEwAHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=linux%20kernel%20book%20__GFP_COMP&f=false) book and the excellent article:
[Kernel Korner - Allocating Memory in the Kernel](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6930) for more information.

As you can see, you are requesting 4096 KiB of non-blocking allocation,
allocation must remain atomic; you can't block the allocation
and try to free the memory (continuous).  The allocation thus fails.

Flags can be found at `include/linux/gfp.h`
(see [source 1](https://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.4.4/include/linux/gfp.h#L70), [source 2](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/gfp.h)).

**Edit – Kernel version 4.9**

That is important information  the kernel version 4.9. 
There has been a regression at this exact kernel version (4.9)
which caused SWAP not to be used at all – [OOM but no swap used (kernel.org)](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190351).

Recommended way to fix it is to upgrade kernel to at least 4.10.8. 
This version and above should have this bug fixed
– more at [OOM but no swap used (Red Hat)](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1401012)

__________________ 
<sup>*</sup>   Presumably they mean kibibytes. 
<sup>**</sup> Presumably they mean KiB.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your help. But It does not directly relate to my question.

Comment: @John you are welcome.  Could you be more specific in your question?  What exactly are you looking for?  This explains why there is free space even when you get a memory page error.

Comment: This answer is also helpful to me indeed. I am grateful to you. You see, the kernel complains when allocating memory with the size of order:10(i.e.page allocation failure: order:10). But there are free blocks indeed(i.e.  "58*4096kB (C)" ). So I think it should not complain since there are enough free memory indeed.

Comment: @John well your allocation fails due to the nature of the request for the memory allocator.  See my edit, which should explain it in greater detail.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found nothing useful but comment on "__GFP_COMP" throughout the source code of the kernel, which says:"%__GFP_COMP address compound page metadata". I googled it, but I still did not find out where the "The page frame belongs to extended page" comes from.

Comment: @John flags are defined at `include/linux/gfp.h`

Comment: Yes, I have seen the same file(refer to https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/gfp.h#L297), but I could not there is any statement indicates "the page frame belongs to extended page" when using __GFP_COMP.

Comment: @John You can't find that in the code. You will find it in the Linux Kernel book as I have suggested.  I have added link to the answer.