# allocating contiguous memory in QEMU VM result in failure in alloc_pages_nodemask

Tags: memory, qemu

I am trying to allocate around 33M of contiguous memory but most of the times it fails in `__alloc_pages_nodemask` call. This is a QEMU Guest OS, and the kernel version I am using is 5.9.1. This contains around 16GB of memory.

Same kernel on a physical PC is able to allocate this amount of memory.

I have tried the method suggested in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593335/why-does-page-allocation-failure-occur-whereas-there-are-still-enough-memoryi) but no luck.